# SqlDataAdapter.Fill method does not give any error but also not return any data for long running query ado.net core SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-core, stored-procedures, ado.net, database-connection, sqldataadapter

I am using SQLDataAdapter to fill the dataset, results I am getting from the SQL server stored procedure. My SP is getting executed in the backend database which takes around 30Sec to execute. But DataAdatpter.Fill get executed in fraction of second without returning any kind of exception (including timeout). Wondering whats happening because of no data in dataset I am not able to proceed further.

I tried setting connection and command timeout to 360 Secs even though there is no timeout exception.
I tried using SQLDataReader instead of Adapter still no results.
I tried and added using clause for connection adapter no luck.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(true)))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SearchCompanies]"))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 360;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

                /*Method 1*/
                //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //da.Fill(ds);

        //con.Open();   
                /*Method 2*/
                //using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                //{
                //    int i = 0;
                //    do
                //    {
                //        ds.Tables[i].Load(sdr);
                //        i++;
                //    }
                //    while (sdr.NextResult());
                //}
                //con.Close();

                /*Method 3*/
                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    try
                    {
                       adapter.Fill(ds); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }

                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
```

I do not get any error message even command time-out for this long running process.

I am expecting Data adapter should get some results from long running SP's in .net CORE ADO.net

Comment: All that code looks fine.  Create a simplified stored procedure with the same signature to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. I debugged the code and later found that this issue is due to one of the Boolean input parameter was null. By handling the boolean values issue got resolved